# How do I fix my ruby regex

Tags: ruby, regex, escaping

I want to write a regexp that matches any of the following four characters: /, *, -, +

But I'm having trouble with / and *

If I write `/*/+-/` there are problems

I tried using Regex.escape but it's not doing what I expect: I tried `/#{Regex.escape('[+-/*]')}/` and `/#{Regex.escape('[+-\/\*]')}/`

Comment: Did you try simply `/\/\*-\+/` (I don't need you need it for `-`)?

Comment: Your second regex should work.

Comment: Are you trying to match one of or all of them? If one of, then I would modify my suggestion to be `/[\/\*\-\*]/`

Comment: @mbratch "match any of ..." → "match one at a time".

Comment: Cool. Then I would use `/[\/*+-]/`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the percent literal will help for `/`. Within `[]` alternatives, you don't need to escape `*` and `+`, and you don't need to escape `-` if you put it at the beginning or the end.

```
%r{[/*+-]}
```